# Как записать результат выполнения цикла for в переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть у меня такой код:

```
import os
import xml.dom.minidom

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/users/fedyunin_es/desktop/defaultVars"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".substvar"):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))**

        for element in #НУЖНО УКАЗАТЬ ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ()

            doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(element)
            data ={}

        for info in doc.getElementsByTagName("globalVariable"):
            name = str(info.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].firstChild.data)
            value = str(info.getElementsByTagName("value")[0].firstChild.data)
            data[name]=value
        print(element,"\n",data,"\n")
```

Собственно, вопрос, как мне результат первого цикла, выделенного ** записать в переменную?

[image: разница при print(li) и print изначального цикла]

Comment: У цикла `for` может быть результат?) Я плохо понимаю, что Вы имеете в виду. Если Вам нужно сохранять значения, которые печатаются, то заведите список и добавляйте туда их, потом итерируйте его.

Comment: Да, в результате выполнения цикла у меня печатается на экран список директорий, в которых лежат нужные файлы. Нужно этот список директорий записать в переменную, что бы ее передавать в второй цикл.

Answer (score 1):

Сохраняйте полученные значения в список (в примере это `li`), потом итерируйте его.

Единственное, Вам может потребоваться изменить вложенность последующих циклов `for`, чтобы не повторять одни и те же действия на каждой итерации внешнего цикла.

***Пример:***

```
...
li = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/users/fedyunin_es/desktop/defaultVars"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".substvar"):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            print(path)
            li.append(path)

for element in li:
    ....
```

Comment: Летит в ошибку. 
    value = str(info.getElementsByTagName("value")[0].firstChild.data)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

Не нужно ли добавить преобразование li в list?

Comment: @Евгений Это уже совсем другой вопрос. Он не относится к моему коду, так как список обрабатывается корректно. Задайте его отдельно.

Comment: кажется, что проблема именно в полученном списке, и его некорректно распознает дальнейший цикл.

Comment: @Евгений Причём тут список?) В него добавляются те же элементы, что и печатаются Вам на экран. Если Вы не верите мне, то распечатайте его функцией `print` и убедитесь в этом сами.

Comment: В том то и дело, что сделал print.
print(li) выводит нам список в одну строку, каждая запись обрамлена ' ', а простой принт изначального кода - список директорий без обрамлений ' ' и каждая директория на новой строке. Попробую прикрепить скрин к вопросу.

Comment: @Евгений Это несмешная шутка, пранк?) Вы же его итерируете в цикле `for`. На каждой итерации в переменной `element` будет содержаться конкретный путь. "Обрамления" (`''`) означают, что это строка. При печати или обращении к конкретному элементу их не будет. Я не хочу более продолжать эту дискуссию, этот кусок кода до невозможности очевиден.